# Rotations and reflections in dihedral group $D_8?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, dihedral-groups

My question is:

> In the dihedral group $D_8$, generated by $\alpha,\beta $, with $\alpha^8=\beta^2=e$, prove that $\alpha^7\beta=\beta\alpha$. Hence write $(\alpha^3\beta)(\alpha^2\beta)$ in the form $\alpha^p\beta^q$.

I can visualise the rotations $\alpha$ and reflections $\beta$ of the octagon $D_8$ but I am not sure how to prove the statement $\alpha^7\beta=\beta \alpha$. For the second part, through visualisation, I got $\alpha^2\beta^0$ but I am not sure how I would show this mathematically.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is your _definition_ of the dihedral group? Because to me, $\beta\alpha=\alpha^{-1}\beta$ is part of the definition, and thus trivial to show.

Comment: This is your sixth question here and yet you do not use MathJax nor have you accepted any answers.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this website so I'm not sure how to use MathJax or accept answers so I've just been upvoting them instead

Comment: There's a check mark that allows you to accept an answer to your questions.  More importantly, what's the answer to the question @Arthur asks above?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include your definition of $D_8$.

Comment: There is a MathJax guide [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to visualise $\beta\alpha\beta^{-1}=\alpha^{-1}$ and therefore  $\beta\alpha=\alpha^{-1}\beta=\alpha^{7}\beta$ for the first part.

Also, since $\beta\alpha\beta^{-1}=\alpha^{-1}$ we have $\beta\alpha^2\beta^{-1}=\alpha^{-2}$ and therefore $$(\alpha^3\beta)(\alpha^2\beta)=\alpha^3(\beta\alpha^2\beta)=\alpha^3\alpha^{-2}=\alpha.$$

Answer (score 0):

For the second part, just walk $\beta$ through the various instances of $\alpha$ one by one:

$$\begin{align}
\beta\alpha^2&=(\beta \alpha)\alpha \\
&= (\alpha^7\beta)\alpha \\
&= \alpha^7(\beta\alpha)\\
&=\alpha^{14}\beta\\
&=\alpha^6\beta.
\end{align}$$